# Почему рамка не появляется в div `e?

Tags: css

```css
div.center {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    border-color:red;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:60px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="MyStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="center" class="center">
        
        <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="login" >
        <p id="loginError"></p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password">
            <p id="passwordError"></p>
        </div> 
        <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `border-style:solid;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div.center {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:60px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="MyStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="center" class="center">
        
        <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="login" >
        <p id="loginError"></p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password">
            <p id="passwordError"></p>
        </div> 
        <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```